# ms access database runs without errors but the database is not modified

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to add data to a ms access database, it runs without errors but the database is not modified. Am I wrong or I forgot something?

```
//using System.Data.OleDb;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Projects\Cinema.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

     OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);  
     con.Open(); 
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into seats(number)" + "Values(1)", con);
     con.Close();
}
```

Comment: whew... three answers in one minute ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to execute your command.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about calling [cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should execute the command.

In your case:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```